# It is possible to delay the execution of a function on Today Extensions (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I want to delay the execution of a method inside a framework that gets loaded from within a Today Extension.

I have tried this:

A function that receives the task and the time to wait

```
func playCPUWithDelay(delayInMilliSeconds:Int64,scheduledTask: ()->Void)
 {

    let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,delayInMilliSeconds) // 1
    dispatch_after(popTime, GlobalMainQueue) { // 2

    scheduledTask()

}
```

being

```
var GlobalMainQueue: dispatch_queue_t {
return dispatch_get_main_queue()
}
```

but it gets runned without delay

also have also tried..

```
NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(5000))
```

but this call hangs up the app, making it unresponsive for more than that time and until forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch_time` takes a time delta in nanoseconds, not in milliseconds, so it's likely your function actually works, it's just off by a factor of 1000000.  Try:

```
let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInMilliseconds * NSEC_PER_MSEC)
```